# Prevent file creation if query returns no data

Tags: mysql, sql, export-to-csv

I have a job that runs every night which executes a query and exports the result of that query into a .csv file.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
SELECT Your_Column_Name
FROM Your_Table_Name
INTO OUTFILE 'Filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

My question is: is there any way to prevent the file creation if the query returns a total rowcount of 0 without having to execute the query twice? Once to count the row and twice to create the file?

Comment: You could check the file to see if it has only one row (indicating no data), and then delete it.  Or, you could write a proc and check the count before writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to prevent creation of the file without writing a little more code.

You don't necessarily need to *count* the rows, if all you want to know is whether there are zero rows or more than zero rows.

```
SELECT 1 FROM Your_Table_Name LIMIT 1
```

This will return 1 row if there are any matching rows, or else it will return zero rows. If you're concerned that counting *all* matching rows is too slow, then this will return more quickly.